# Plotting two heat maps side by side in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a function that plots the heat map for the correlation matrix of a DataFrame. The function looks like this:

```
def corr_heatmap(data):
    columns = data.columns
    corr_matrix = data.corr()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
    mat = ax.matshow(corr_matrix, cmap='coolwarm')

    ax.set_xticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(columns)
    ax.set_yticklabels(columns)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='left', rotation_mode='anchor')
    plt.colorbar(mat, fraction=0.045, pad=0.05)
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    return mat
```

and when run with a DataFrame outputs something like this:

[image]

What I want to do is plot two of these heat maps side by side, but I'm having some trouble doing so. What I've done so far is attempt to assign each heat map to an AxesImage object and use subplots to plot them.

```
mat1 = corr_heatmap(corr_mat1)
mat2 = corr_heatmap(corr_mat2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax1.plot(ma1)
ax2.plot(ma2)
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AxesImage'
```

Would anybody happen to know a way that I could plot two heat map images side by side? Thank you.

**EDIT**

In case anyone's wondering what the final code for what I wanted to do would look like:

```
def corr_heatmaps(data1, data2, method='pearson'):

    # Basic Configuration
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 12))
    ax1, ax2 = axes
    corr_matrix1 = data1.corr(method=method)
    corr_matrix2 = data2.corr(method=method)
    columns1 = corr_matrix1.columns
    columns2 = corr_matrix2.columns

    # Heat maps.
    im1 = ax1.matshow(corr_matrix1, cmap='coolwarm')
    im2 = ax2.matshow(corr_matrix2, cmap='coolwarm')

    # Formatting for heat map 1.
    ax1.set_xticks(range(len(columns1)))
    ax1.set_yticks(range(len(columns1)))
    ax1.set_xticklabels(columns1)
    ax1.set_yticklabels(columns1)
    ax1.set_title(data1.name, y=-0.1)
    plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='left', rotation_mode='anchor')
    plt.colorbar(im1, fraction=0.045, pad=0.05, ax=ax1)

    # Formatting for heat map 2.
    ax2.set_xticks(range(len(columns2)))
    ax2.set_yticks(range(len(columns2)))
    ax2.set_xticklabels(columns2)
    ax2.set_yticklabels(columns2)
    ax2.set_title(data2.name, y=-0.1)
    plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='left', rotation_mode='anchor')
    plt.colorbar(im2, fraction=0.045, pad=0.05, ax=ax2)

    fig.tight_layout()
```

This could (when run with two Pandas DataFrames) outputs something along the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is the `plt.subplots` function. Instead of manually adding `Axes` objects to a `Figure`, you can initialise a `Figure` along with a number of `Axes`. Then, it is as simple as calling `matshow` on each `Axes`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))

ax1, ax2 = axes

im1 = ax1.matshow(df.corr())
im2 = ax2.matshow(df.corr())

fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)
```

[image]

You can perform all the other formatting later.

Comment: hi @gmds, do you know how can I use the same colorbar for both heatmaps?

Comment: @NimrodMorag You should ask a new question.

Comment: Hey, where to add annotation option?

Answer (score -1):

Please, Follow the below example, change the plot to matshow, do axis customization as per your need.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def f(t): 
    return np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2*np.pi*t) 

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01) 

ax1 = plt.subplot(121) 
ax1.plot(t1, f(t1), 'k') 

ax2 = plt.subplot(122) 
ax2.plot(t1, f(t1), 'r') 
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ranjeet. Unfortunately this is not what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm already familiar with how to make simple subplots with Matplotlib. The reason I posted the question is because I wanted to utilize the custom function I made to output two heat maps side by side.